# Loading worker file in webpack 5 + Angular 13 on ng serve

Tags: angular, webpack, worker

I am facing the issue after I upgraded my project from angular 12 to angular 13(including webpack upgradation from webpack 4 to webpack 5).

**Before upgrade**

```js
import \* as testworker from 'worker-loader!./test.worker.bundle.js';
```

**After upgrade to webpack 5**

```js
const testworker = new Worker(new URL("test.worker.bundle.js", import.meta.url));
```

I had to change as mentioned above after upgrade to webpack 5 to make ng build successful. But when we run application on ng serve getting **runtime** error
with '***DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at** 'file::/// Path to js file' 'http://localhost: test.worker.bundle.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'http://localhost:4200'.

I tried adjusting output block in config file as well. None of them is solving the issue.

Output block in config file is as below.

```json
"output": {
     "path": process.cwd(),
     "filename": "\[name\].js"
},
```

Let me know if anywhere else has to be changed.

I tried adjusting the output block in config file and setting the path to js file in URL params